# How to force conan2 to use different cmake generator

Tags: cmake, mingw, conan, conan-2

I want to package my conan project on Windows. When I use this host profile conan always tries to find a compiler corresponding to `Unix Makefiles`:

```
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=20
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=11
os=Linux
```

Which then yields the following error:

```
..
cojson/0.1.0: Calling build()
cojson/0.1.0: Running CMake.configure()
cojson/0.1.0: RUN: cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:/Users/Samuel/.conan2/p/b/cojsoab8131f7efa0a/b/build/Release/generators/conan_toolchain.cmake" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/Users/Samuel/.conan2/p/b/cojsoab8131f7efa0a/p" -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091="NEW" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" "C:\Users\Samuel\.conan2\p\b\cojsoab8131f7efa0a\b"
Der Befehl "." ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

The last bit translates to "the command "." is either misspelled or could not be found. Invoking the command seperately yields more informative results:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
```

I get that I have no compiler corresponding to `Unix Makefiles` installed. But how can I hint conan in the direction that I want to use `MinGW`?

### I tried

to set a `build_env` variable of the host settings to hint the generator to CMake:

```
[buildenv]
CMAKE_GENERATOR="MingGW Makefiles"
```

However of course that doesn't work as the `-G` option is passed by conan which overwrites environment variables.

I can't find any conan2 (!) documentation on how I can switch generators.

I also tried to switch settings.os to Windows instead of Linux to nudge Conan in the right direction but still same output.

Answer (score 1):

To select a particular generator, add `tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=MinGW Makefiles` to the `[conf]` section of your profile.

You probably should specify that you're on Windows instead of `os=Linux` as well.

Comment: Thanks, that switches the generator indeed. I can still not build, the error staying the same. However, when I try to build from the gtest conan cache it works with MinGW. I don't see through this.

Comment: @glades What's the new error message?  I'm assuming you're missing the `CC=<path-to-mingw-gcc>` and `CXX=<path-to-mingw-g++>` entries in the `[env]` section of the profile so that conan actually uses MinGW, but without the error message I'm not sure.